# I want to put a single function in forms.py rather than two in views.py

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
class CreateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'tasks/form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CreateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
        ctx['action'] = 'Add'
        ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.list')
        return ctx


    def form_valid(self, form):
        task_object = form.save(self.request.user, commit=False)
        admin_time = form.cleaned_data['admin_time']
        if admin_time:
            task_object.execution_time=admin_time
            task_object.save(self.request.user)
        messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been created.'))
        return redirect('tasks.list')

class UpdateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'tasks/form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(UpdateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
        ctx['action'] = 'Update'
        ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.detail', args=[self.get_object().id])
        return ctx

    def form_valid(self, form):
        admin_time = form.cleaned_data.get('admin_time')
        if admin_time:
            self.object.execution_time = admin_time
            self.object.save()
        form.save(self.request.user)


        messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been updated.'))
        return redirect('tasks.list')
```

I have the same function being used in both the classes: `def form_valid(self,form)`

Will it be possible to add this validation in the form itself?

my **forms.py**

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    keywords = (forms.CharField(
                help_text=_('Please use commas to separate your keywords.'),
                required=False,
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'medium-field'})))
    admin_time = forms.CharField(
                help_text=_('Enter If more than 60 minutes.'),
                required=False,
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['instance']:
            initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
            initial['keywords'] = kwargs['instance'].keywords_list
            kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _process_keywords(self, creator):
        if 'keywords' in self.changed_data:
            kw = [k.strip() for k in self.cleaned_data['keywords'].split(',')]
            self.instance.replace_keywords(kw, creator)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        if start_date and end_date:
            if start_date >= end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))
        admin_time = cleaned_data.get('admin_time')

        if admin_time:
            execution_time=admin_time
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, creator, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.creator = creator
        super(TaskForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('commit', True):
            self._process_keywords(creator)
        return self.instance

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/admin_ace.css',)
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'execution_time', 'difficulty',
              'priority', 'repeatable', 'team', 'project', 'type', 'start_date',
              'end_date', 'why_this_matters', 'prerequisites', 'instructions',
              'is_draft', 'is_invalid')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
            'short_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
            'instructions': AceWidget(mode='markdown', theme='textmate', width='800px',
                                  height='300px', wordwrap=True,
                                  attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}),
            'start_date': CalendarInput,
            'end_date': CalendarInput,
            'why_this_matters': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
            'prerequisites': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        }
```

I tried editing in 
    `def clean(self)`, but it doesn't work. when I remove the if admin_time validation from views.py

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `save()` method of modelform to do this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(TaskForm, self).save(commit=False)
        admin_time = self.cleaned_data['admin_time']
        if admin_time:
            instance.execution_time=admin_time
        instance.save()
        return instance
```